# ffmpeg, vlc - Unable to find input stream

Tags: stream, streaming, ffmpeg, vlc

Good day to all... I have some "little" problems with ffserver and ffmpeg...

What I need to do is to broadcast a live video. So I got the cam... used vlc and used send stream option. I sent it to 192.168.1.9:64555, which is a virtual machine on the same computer, running centos.

On the virtual machine I run the command ffmpeg -i 192.168.1.9:64555 output.mpg.

The response is "unable to find file whatever".

Can any1 tell me what I did wrong?

Thank you and have a great day.

Print-screen with error:

[image]

Comment: it is not a question to stackoverflow, maybe move it to superuser?  Also, please, post an exact error message here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Good day. I found the answer at the question. The problem was that ffmpeg can't manage live streams. It should be created a pipe.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that `ffmpeg` don't realize that it asked to open a network stream. So, it try to open the file with name "192.168.1.9:65444", not to connect a network on this address.

I suggest you consult the manual of ffmpeg. The network stream should have some prefix like udp:// or **rtp://** or anything (the vlc itself uses such prefix)